# Jquery swipe unbinded when open an iframe

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I´m working with [JQuery.mobile-1.2.1](https://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/)   swipe events and MVC4.
I defined the event in main view like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dummy-forswipe").on("swipeleft", swipeleftHandler); 
    $(".dummy-forswipe").on("swiperight", swiperightHandler); 
});
```

This works great, but the problem appears when i open and close an iframe, for some reason lose this events when i close the iframe (bootstrap modal style) and the only way to recover the events is tapping on the div with the class .dummy-forswipe in the main view to restore all the events.

I tried to rebind the events in main view:

```
 $("#ModalBreach").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
          $(".dummy-forswipe").on("swipeleft", swipeleftHandler); 
          $(".dummy-forswipe").on("swiperight", swiperightHandler); 
   });
```

But nothing happen...
Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simulated a click to the first td with the class dummy-forswipe.
This is how i fixed:

```
$("#ModalBreach").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
            if (typeof $('td[class^="dummy-forswipe"]')[0] != 'undefined') {
                $('td[class^="dummy-forswipe"]')[0].click();
            }
        });
```